Getting build error for fabric. Can someone assist on this?
I'm trying to build the development environment for hyperledger fabric from : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric, fabric 2.2.14; While running make command I am getting leveldb: closed error.
I am getting below error for make command.
2024-04-02 13:00:09.815 IST [leveldbhelper] Get -> ERRO 010 Error retrieving leveldb key [[]byte{0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x67, 0x65, 0x74, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x73, 0x70, 0x69, 0x64, 0x73, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x67, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x76, 0x65, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x73, 0x0, 0x6e, 0x1, 0x3}]: leveldb: closed


2024-04-02 13:00:21.623 IST [kvlegetActiveLedgerIDsdger]  -> ERRO 17e Error getting ledger ids from idStore: leveldb: closed


2024-04-02 13:00:23.454 IST [kvledger] getActiveLedgerIDs -> ERRO 19a Error unmarshalling ledger metadata: unexpected EOF
2024-04-02 13:00:23.454 IST [kvledger] getLedgerMetadata -> ERRO 19b Error unmarshalling ledger metadata: unexpected EOF
2024-04-02 13:00:23.772 IST [kvledger] openIDStore -> ERRO 19c The db at path [/tmp/kvledger656871058/ledgerProvider] contains data in unexpected format. expected data format = [2.0] ([]byte{0x32, 0x2e, 0x30}), data format = [] ([]byte(nil)).
2024-04-02 13:00:23.774 IST [kvledger] func1 -> ERRO 19d Please execute the 'peer node upgrade-dbs' command to upgrade the database format: unexpected format. db info = [leveldb for channel-IDs at [/tmp/kvledger656871058/ledgerProvider]], data format = [], expected format = [2.0]


2024-04-02 13:01:41.137 IST [kvledger] updateLedgerStatus -> ERRO 941 LedgerID [dummy] does not exist
2024-04-02 13:01:41.430 IST [kvledger] updateLedgerStatus -> ERRO 942 LedgerID [dummy] does not exist
2024-04-02 13:01:41.745 IST [kvledger] getLedgerMetadata -> ERRO 943 Error unmarshalling ledger metadata: unexpected EOF
2024-04-02 13:01:42.014 IST [kvledger] getLedgerMetadata -> ERRO 944 Error unmarshalling ledger metadata: unexpected EOF


2024-04-02 13:02:07.152 IST [lockbasedtxmgr] RemoveStaleAndCommitPvtDataOfOldBlocks -> DEBU a65 Constructing unique pvtData by removing duplicate entries
--- FAIL: TestGenerateSnapshotErrors (9.52s)
    --- FAIL: TestGenerateSnapshotErrors/block_store_returns_error (1.46s)
        snapshot_test.go:239: 
                Error Trace:    snapshot_test.go:239
                Error:          "leveldb: closed\ninternal leveldb error while obtaining db iterator\ngithub.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper.(*DBHandle).GetIterator\n\t/home/manisha/Downloads/fabric/demoTh/fabric-2.2.14/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper/leveldb_provider.go:240\ngithub.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage.(*blockIndex).exportUniqueTxIDs\n\t/home/manisha/Downloads/fabric/demoTh/fabric-2.2.14/common/ledger/blkstorage/blockindex.go:276\ngithub.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage.(*BlockStore).ExportTxIds\n\t/home/manisha/Downloads/fabric/demoTh/fabric-2.2.14/common/ledger/blkstorage/blockstore.go:100\ngithub.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.(*kvLedger).generateSnapshot\n\t/home/manisha/Downloads/fabric/demoTh/fabric-2.2.14/core/ledger/kvledger/snapshot.go:60\ngithub.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.TestGenerateSnapshotErrors.func4\n\t/home/manisha/Downloads/fabric/demoTh/fabric-2.2.14/core/ledger/kvledger/snapshot_test.go:235\ntesting.tRunner\n\t/usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1595\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650" does not contain "fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/blockindex.go"
                Test:           TestGenerateSnapshotErrors/block_store_returns_error
    --- FAIL: TestGenerateSnapshotErrors/config_history_mgr_returns_error (1.38s)
        snapshot_test.go:249: 
                Error Trace:    snapshot_test.go:249
                Error:          "leveldb: closed\ninternal leveldb error while obtaining db iterator\ngithub.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper.(*DBHandle).GetIterator\n\t/home/manisha/Downloads/fabric/demoTh/fabric-2.2.14/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper/leveldb_provider.go:240\ngithub.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/confighistory.(*db).getNamespaceIterator\n\t/home/manisha/Downloads/fabric/demoTh/fabric-2.2.14/core/ledger/confighistory/db_helper.go:114\ngithub.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/confighistory.(*Retriever).ExportConfigHistory\n\t/home/manisha/Downloads/fabric/demoTh/fabric-2.2.14/core/ledger/confighistory/mgr.go:233\ngithub.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.(*kvLedger).generateSnapshot\n\t/home/manisha/Downloads/fabric/demoTh/fabric-2.2.14/core/ledger/kvledger/snapshot.go:64\ngithub.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.TestGenerateSnapshotErrors.func5\n\t/home/manisha/Downloads/fabric/demoTh/fabric-2.2.14/core/ledger/kvledger/snapshot_test.go:245\ntesting.tRunner\n\t/usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1595\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650" does not contain "fabric/core/ledger/confighistory/mgr.go"
                Test:           TestGenerateSnapshotErrors/config_history_mgr_returns_error
2024-04-02 13:02:07.833 IST [leveldbhelper] openDBAndCheckFormat -> INFO a66 DB is empty Setting db format as 2.0

